# How can I concatenate multiple rows of excel data into one?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm currently facing an issue where I need to bring all of the data shown in the images below into one line only.

[image]

So using Python and Openpyxl, I tried to write a parsing script that reads the line and only copies when values are non-null or non-identical, into a new workbook.

I get out of range errors, and the code does not keep just the data I want. I've spent multiple hours on it, so I thought I would ask here to see if I can get unstuck.

I've read some documentation on Openpyxl and about making lists in python, tried a couple of videos on youtube, but none of them did exactly what I was trying to achieve.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

path = "sample.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active
path2 = "output.xlsx"
wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active

listab = []
rows = ws.max_row
columns = ws.max_column

for i in range (1, rows+1):
   listab.append([])

cellValue = " "    
prevCell = " "

for c in range (1, rows+1):
    for r in range(1, columns+1):
        cellValue = ws.cell(row=r, column=c).value
            if cellValue == prevCell:
                listab[r-1].append(prevCell)
            elif cellValue == "NULL":
                listab[r-1].append(prevCell)
            elif cellValue != prevCell:
                listab[r-1].append(cellValue)
                prevCell = cellValue           

for r in range(1, rows+1):
    for c in range (1, columns+1):
        j = ws2.cell(row = r, column=c)
        j.value = listab[r-1][c-1]

print(listab)

wb2.save("output.xlsx")
```

There should be one line with the below information:

ods_service_id | service_name| service_plan_name| CPU | RAM | NIC | DRIVE |

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. Please describe what you want to do with individual rows.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go with `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

#Loading into pandas
df_data = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')
df_data.fillna("NO DATA",inplace=True)  ## Replaced nan values with "NO DATA"
unique_ids = df_data.ods_service_ids.unique()

#Storing pd into a list
records_list = df_data.to_dict('records') 
keys_to_check = ['service_name', 'service_plan_name', 'CPU','RAM','NIC','DRIVE']
processed = {}

#Go through unique ids
for key in unique_ids:
    processed[key] = {}

    #Get related records
    matching_records = [y for y in records_list if y['ods_service_ids'] == key]
    #Loop through records
    for record in matching_records:
        #For each key to check, save in dict if non null
        processed[key]['ods_service_ids'] = key
        for detail_key in keys_to_check:
            if record[detail_key] != "NO DATA" :
                processed[key][detail_key] = record[detail_key]
        ##Note : doesn't handle duplicate values for different keys so far


#Records are put back in list
output_data = [processed[x] for x in processed.keys()]
# -> to Pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(output_data)[['ods_service_ids','service_name', 'service_plan_name', 'CPU','RAM','NIC','DRIVE']]

#Export to Excel
df.to_excel("output.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet_name_1', index=False)
```

The above should work but I wasn't really sure on how you wanted to save duplicated records for the same id. Do you look to store them as `DRIVE_0`, `DRIVE_1`, `DRIVE_2` ?

#### EDIT:

df could be exported in a different way. Replaced below `#export to Excel` with the following :

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx",sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

### EDIT 2:

with no input data it was hard to see any flows. Corrected the code above with fake data

Comment: I think doing the processing Pandas is fine but then I'd write rows directly with openpyxl.

Comment: I tried running this and I get:

````
>>> xcel
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'xcel' is not defined
>>>
>>> writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
>>> df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'df' is not defined
>>> writer.save()

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'writer' is not defined
>>>
````

Comment: @SebastienD it says that df is not defined, which is weird given the fact that you actually define its values. Could it be an error with my Visual Code configuration? I set Environment variables for Python, do I need to do it for each library I add?

Comment: Mathieu, I just ran the code and indeed there were a couple errors. Corrected them, hope it will work. Anyway, do not focus on my approach, please consider what @CharlieClarck suggested which looks interesting

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think you've managed to get confused by data structures and come up with something far more complicated than you need.

One approach that would suit would be to use Python dictionaries for each service, updating them row by row.

```
wb = load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
objs = {}
headers = next(ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, values_only=True))
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    if row[0] not in objs:
        obj = {key:value for key, value in zip(headers, row)}
        objs[obj['ods_service_id']] = obj
    else:# update dict with non-None values
        extra = {key:value for key, value in zip(headers[3:], row[3:]) if value != "NULL"}
        obj.update(extra)

# write to new workbook
wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
ws2.append(headers)
for row in objs.values(): # do they need sorting?
    ws2.append([obj[key] for key in headers])
```

Note how you can do everything without using counters.

Comment: For the most part this runs, but it is telling me that for "header", in zip(header, row), header is not defined. because of that error though, the script fails to write anything in output.xlsx

Comment: seems the header issue was indeed the S missing.

So the code continues running here and I'm getting a keyerror on line 13 : objs[obj['ods_service_id']] = obj

Comment: What does `obj.keys()` give you? Or what's the first value of ´headers`?